# getting data from multiple tables and applying arithmatic operation on the result

Tags: mysql, database, join, sum, left-join

I want to fetch data from two table and apply arithmetic operation on the column.

This is wha I tried :

```
String sql = "SELECT SUM(S.san_recover-C.amount) as total 
              FROM sanction S 
              LEFT JOIN collection C ON S.client_id = C.client_id 
              WHERE S.client_id=?";
```

This code is working only when there is value in both tables, but if there is no value in one of two tables there is no result.

Comment: That is the way query would work because the calculated field has direct dependency on both tables? What is it that you want when data is not present in one or either of the columns.

Comment: 1 column is amount given and second column is amount collected. so i want difference of both column

Comment: You asked this question on 16th oct and you claimed to have resolved it - what didn't work. BTW I think my answer would work..

Comment: @p.Salmon its actually working only if there is data in both tables. if one of table have null value its not working

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(S.san_recover - C.amount) as total 
FROM sanction S 
LEFT JOIN collection C ON S.client_id = C.client_id 
WHERE S.client_id = ?
```

The problem with your query lies in the `SUM()` function. When the left join does not bring back records, then `c.amount` is `NULL`. When substracting `NULL` from something, you get a `NULL` result, which then propagates across the computation, and you end up with a `NULL` result for the `SUM()`.

You probably want `COALESCE()`, like so:

```
SELECT SUM(S.san_recover - COALESCE(C.amount, 0)) as total 
FROM sanction S 
LEFT JOIN collection C ON S.client_id = C.client_id 
WHERE S.client_id = ?
```

Comment: THANKS SIR THIS HAS RESOLVED MY PROBLEM. ITS NOW ACCEPTING NULL VALUES ALSO

Comment: there is another problem. table  sanction have client_id as primary but in collection its multiple entries. so result is not as expected. plz help in this regard

Answer (score 0):

Where there is a possibility that a client may exist in one table but no another a full join would be appropriate but since mysql does not have such a thing then a union in a sub query will do

```
drop table if exists sanctions,collections;

create table sanctions(client_id int, amount int);
create table collections(client_id int, amount int);

insert into  sanctions values 
(1,10),(1,10),(2,10);
insert into  collections values
(1,5),(3,10);

Select sum(Samount - camount)
From
(Select sum(amount) Samount, 0 as camount from sanctions where client_id =3
 Union all
 Select 0,sum(amount) as camount from collections where client_id =3
) s
;

+------------------------+
| sum(Samount - camount) |
+------------------------+
|                    -10 |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you want to do this for all clients

```
Select client_id,sum(Samount - camount) net
From
(Select client_id,sum(amount) Samount, 0 as camount from sanctions group by client_id
 Union all
 Select client_id,0,sum(amount) as camount from collections group by client_id
) s
group by client_id
;
+-----------+------+
| client_id | net  |
+-----------+------+
|         1 |   15 |
|         2 |   10 |
|         3 |  -10 |
+-----------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```